# What is an example of an infinite group (say $G$) and a subgroup $H$ of $G$ which has index $2$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I know an infinite group has an order which, in a sense cannot be found. But would would be an example of a subgroup which has an index 2?

Comment: Hint: think of the integers...

Comment: What do you mean "cannot be found"?

Comment: A different example would be $\mathbb{Z}\times C_2$, where $C_2$ is the cyclic group of order two. Clearly the subgroup corresponding to $\mathbb{Z}$ has index two here. More generally, *any* group which maps onto $C_2$ fits the bill. This is often a much easier approach than trying to find a specific subgroup (especially when you are given a presentation - you just find the abelianisation and go from there...).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a nice non-abelian example: the [*infinite dihedral group*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infinite_dihedral_group) $D_\infty$.  This can be defined in a number of ways, but my preferred definition is as the *isometry group* (that is, the group of maps that preserve distances) of $\mathbb{Z}$.  This leads to the group presentation $\langle t,r\ |\ r^2=1, rtr=t^{-1}\rangle$, where $r$ represents the reflection about the origin whereas $t$ represents a single-unit translation.  Then the subgroup $T=\langle t\rangle$ of just the translations satisfies $T \cong\mathbb{Z}$; it's a nice straightforward exercise to prove that $T$ is a normal subgroup of $D_\infty$ with $D_\infty/T \cong \langle r\rangle \cong C_2$.